# Compare rich / cheap options on 2 underlyings

Tags: options, implied-volatility, beta, realized

this question can turn out to be very basic but its something that has been bugging me.

Say I want to buy/sell an option on A vs sell/buy an option on B.
Facts I know

1. A and B are different underlyings but do have some "beta" between them with a correlation of say 65%, the beta is 1.3 on changes ( i.e. change in A = 1.3* change in B)
2. IV_A/IV_B = 1.15
3. IV_A / HV_A = 1.3 (implied vol is 10% above 20d historical realized vol)
   and IV_B/ HV_B = 1.1

So my confusion is
Looking at 1) and 2) I think I should be buying option on A, vs selling on B
Looking at 3) I should be selling option on A, vs buying on B

What should the right trade be?

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8369/beta-vs-implied-volatility-statistical-arbitrage-using-options